# How can you tell if a QMutex is locked or not?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Does anyone know how to check and see if a QMutex is locked, without using the function:

`bool QMutex::tryLock()`

The reason I don't want to use tryLock() is because it does two things:

1. Check and see if the mutex is locked.
2. If it's not locked then lock it.

For my purposes, I am not interested in performing this second step (locking the mutex).

I just want to know if it is locked or not.

Comment: Why locking by ::tryLock bothers you? You can unlock it right after obtaining lock.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I'm guessing there is no real way to do what I'm asking without actually using tryLock().

This could be accomplished with the following code:

```
bool is_locked = true;

if( a_mutex.tryLock() )
{
    a_mutex.unlock();
    is_locked = false;
}

if( is_locked )
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see, it unlocks the QMutex, "a_mutex", if it was able to lock it.

Of course, this is not a perfect solution, as by the time it hits the 2nd if statement, the mutex's status could have changed.

Answer (score 25):

Trying to lock a mutex is by definition the only way to tell if it's locked; otherwise when this imaginary function returned, how would you know if the mutex was *still* locked? It may have become unlocked while the function was returning; or more importantly, without performing all the cache-flushing and syncronization necessary to lock it, you couldn't actually be sure if it was locked or not.

Comment: -1 Small note, sometimes it is useful to know whether the mutex is locked without trying to lock it, for example for statistics purpose while still without interfering with the threads. So despite your important point, it is not "by definition the only way to tell if it is locked"

Comment: Er, that something would be useful does not imply that it's not impossible by definition.

Comment: -1 It may be impossible but does not help the problem, the other answer are much more helpful although this information is true.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a [QSemaphore](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsemaphore.html) with one permit? The available() method may give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

QMutex is designed just for locking and unlocking functionality. Gathering statistics may be satisfied with some custom counters.
Try QSemaphore as @Luca Carion mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
static bool isLocked(const QBasicMutex *mut) {
  auto mdata = reinterpret_cast<const QBasicAtomicPointer<QMutexData> *>(mut);
  return mdata->load();
}
```

This code should work on Qt 5 and doesn't mess with the mutex state.

Every QBasicMutex holds a single (atomic) pointer (called `d_ptr`) that is NULL if not owned, a special value if it is owned but uncontested or a pointer to a platform dependent structure (on Unix, this is basically a pthread mutex) if the mutex is owned and contested.

We need the reinterpret_cast because `d_ptr` is private.

More info can be found here: https://woboq.com/blog/internals-of-qmutex-in-qt5.html

A legitimate use case is to verify that a mutex is indeed locked, for example if it is a function precondition. I suggest using `Q_ASSERT(isLocked(...))` for this purpose.

Testing for an unlocked mutex is inherently unsafe and should not be done.